traefik with FTPS, tls offlaoding issue
i'm trying to migrate from HAProxy to Traefik, i have an existing config of Haproxy that act as TCP loadbalancer for an FTPS server. i'm trying to do that same with traefik.
The FPTS server operates on port 1413 for control and 1414-1420 to transfer data. my config is the following:
general ciew

Docker-compose.yml
services:
traefik:
image: traefik:2.10
container_name: traefik
network_mode: host
restart: always
env_file:
  - ./traefik.env
volumes:
  - /srv/traefik/:/etc/traefik
  - /srv/traefik/logs:/logs
  - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
command: [ ]

traefik.yml Static config
api:
  insecure: true
  dashboard: true

log:
  level: "DEBUG"
  filePath: "/logs/traefik.log"

certificatesResolvers:
  letsEncrypt:
     acme:
       email: "letencr@cl.ss"  
       storage: "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"    
       tlsChallenge: {}


entryPoints:
  ftps:
    address: ":1413"  
  ftps_data_1:
    address: ":1414"
  ftps_data_2:
    address: ":1415"
  ftps_data_3:
    address: ":1416"
  ftps_data_4:
    address: ":1417"
  ftps_data_5:
    address: ":1418"
  ftps_data_6:
    address: ":1419"
  ftps_data_7:
    address: ":1420"

metrics:
  prometheus: {}

providers:
  file:
    directory: "/etc/traefik/config"
    watch: true

serversTransport:
   insecureSkipVerify: true

tls.yml
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /etc/letsencrypt/certs_project/fullchain.pem
      keyFile: /etc/letsencrypt/certs_project/key.pem

ftps_dynamic_config.yml
tcp:
  routers:
    ## Connect
    hi_ftps_connect:*
      rule: "HostSNI(``)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_connect"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_1:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_1"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_1"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_2:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_2"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_2"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_3:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_3"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_3"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_4:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_4"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_4"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_5:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_5"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_5"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_6:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_6"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_6"
      tls: {}

    ## Data transfer
    hi_ftps_passive_7:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      entryPoints:
        - "ftps_data_7"
      service: "ssl_hi_ftps_passive_7"
      tls: {} 

  services:
    
    ## Connect
    ssl_hi_ftps_connect:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1413" # Connectivity 
        
    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_1:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1414" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_2:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1415" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_3:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1416" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_4:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1417" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_5:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1418" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_6:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1419" # Data 

    ## Data transfer
    ssl_hi_ftps_passive_7:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
        - address: "172.20.49.6:1420" # Data

Treafik logs:
time="#" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from [MY-IP]:45552: tls: client requested unsupported application protocols ([ftp])"
time="#" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from [MY-IP]:45564: tls: client requested unsupported application protocols ([ftp])"

i'm connecting with the Filezilla client
i don't get it, i never setup such a thing with traefik. Also, when the setup was done with haproxy , it prompt me in filezilla to accept the certificate when i try to connect to the ftps server.
anyone that have tried to do such a config kindly provide me with some guidance?
